# Passar variaveis na URL do getjson XDK Intel

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, intel-xdk

Comecei a estudar javascipt agora e preciso passar duas variáveis para um método de soma com getJSON e nao sei como fazer. Criei meu app com o XDK Intel, o server criei com delphi xe2 utilizando datasnap.

Tentei destas duas formas e nao consegui.

```
//alert('acessou a rotina');    
$.get(urlSoma).then(function(data){

    alert(data);   
    //$("#iptResult").val();
    //$("#iptResult").val(data.result);    

}).fail(function(jqXHR,status,error){        
    alert(error);
});


$.ajax({
        url: urlSoma,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {x: pX},
        success: function(json){
            alerta('fungo');
        },
        error: function(json){
            alert('erro');
        }
    });     
});
```

Alguem pode me auxiliar?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Passe o parâmetros com **/**

Exemplo

```
$.get('suaUrl/paramentro1/paramentro2', suaFuncaoRetorno);
function suaFuncaoRetorno(itens){
  console.log(itens);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Esqueça o $.get. Só  $.AJAX já resolve seu problema.
Veja como é a chamada a sua rotina feita em delphi, mas eu creio que não seja diferente das outras formas.
Se fosse em php `urlSoma='somanumeros.php'`, em delphi eu não sei como fica.

p1 e p2 são os numeros que vc deseja somar.
json é o retorno. Depende da sua função no server-side.

```
$.ajax({
        url: urlSoma,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {p1: numero1,
               p2: numero2},
        success: function(json){
            alerta('fungo');
        },
        error: function(json){
            alert('erro');
        }
    });     
})
```

;